# Table of Contents with titletoc is cut off after first page

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

After I inserted titletoc and changed the Table of Contents the ToC ends after the first page is full. Before I added these settings it started a new page automatically.

This is how my Table of Contents looks:
[image]
As you can see the table is cut off during 8.3 and is not continued on the next page.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, BCOR=5mm, ngerman, paper=a4]{scrreprt}
%+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
%| packages einbinden                                                             |
%+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
%| settings                                                               |
%+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

% —– titletoc - format ToC —– %
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{1.5em}}
{\hspace*{-1.5em}}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[3.7em]{}{\contentslabel{2.2em}}{}
{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[6.7em]{}{\contentslabel{2.95em}}{}
{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
% —– End: format ToC —– %

%+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
%| document                                                    |
%+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

 \chapter{ 1 }
   Some example Text
  \section{1.1}
  \section{1.2}
  \section{1.3}
  \section{1.4}

 \chapter{ 2 }
  \section{2.1}
  \section{2.2}
  \section{2.3}
  \section{2.4}
  \section{2.5}

 \chapter{ 3 }
   ...
\end{document}
```

I think that I am missing some options for my titletoc formatting but I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: Are you sure `titletoc` is compatible with `koma-script`?

Comment: I am not sure if it is compatible... I just thought that there is a mistake with my titletoc settings because the others are working

Comment: I don't know well koma-script, but there might be incompatibilities. The table of contents formatting is documented in the `koma-script guide`, §3.9, pp. 65–69.

Comment: Remove package `tocloft`.

Comment: @esdd Do you want to add some kind of answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B Done.

Comment: @esdd Thanks, i'll upvote tomorrow. Ran out of votes today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use package `titletoc` to format your TOC then remove package `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, BCOR=5mm, ngerman, paper=a4,DIV=calc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% replaces the outdated scrpage2
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{scrhack}% if package float is really needed, load scrhack too
\usepackage{csquotes}

% —– titletoc - format ToC —– %
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{1.5em}}
{\hspace*{-1.5em}}{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{section}[3.7em]{}{\contentslabel{2.2em}}{}
{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[6.7em]{}{\contentslabel{2.95em}}{}
{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that KOMA-Script class `scrreprt` loads package `tocbasic` automatically. So maybe its better to remove `titletoc` too und use something like

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, BCOR=5mm, ngerman, paper=a4,DIV=calc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% replaces the outdated scrpage2
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{scrhack}% if package float is really needed, load scrhack too
\usepackage{csquotes}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  tocbeforeskip=1pc
]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocnumwidth=2.2em
]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=3.75em,
  tocnumwidth=2.95em
]{subsection}

\makeatletter
\show\@dotsep
\renewcommand\@dotsep{1}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\section{A Section}\section{A Section}\section{A Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now, a fresh bunch of votes and the first is left here.